# Div with class inner-header will contain three div elements

Tags: html, css

I've to create a div tag with class inner-header will contain three div elements. 
First div element will have a class `logo` with content “Lifestyle Store” which will be a link.

The class logo will contain the following CSS.

```
float: left;    
height: 50px;    
padding: 15px;    
font-size: 20px;     
font-weight: bold;
```

Second div element will have content Sign up and third div element will have content Login with same class header-link to both div elements.
 Both Sign up and login will be linked.
 Class header-link will contain the following CSS.

```
float:right;    
font-size:14px;    
height: 50px;    
padding: 15px 15px;     
font-size:16px;    
font-weight: bold
```

I'm having the problem in doing this code. How can I add div element inside a div?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? What is the expected behavior and what is happening instead? Be sure to post your HTML as well!

Comment: actually, I've to create an index page with the above coding. The problem is that how can I add three div element inside a div? and rest details are given above

Comment: _“The problem is that how can I add three div element inside a div?”_ - by typing the code in your editor …? It is not even remotely clear, what your actual problem is here. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sir, I don't have any code. This is what the question I'm having. And by understanding the question I've to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

Specify **widths** of div boxes that must be around 50% each and if you use margins then reduce it a little bit.